# How to save the CSV file in variable

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm new to Django and Python. I'm trying to compare two CSV files and make a new file as a result (how much both files are different from each other) in my views.py. First, I get those files and set them into a variable, to make sure that the user can select and compare any file with any name. But I got this error.

```
FileNotFoundError at /compare
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fine_name.csv'
```

what I'm expecting is, when the user selects two files and hit on the compare button, they got a new updated CSV file 'update.csv'.

Here is my code

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def comp(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        file1  = request.POST.get('file1', '')
        file2  = request.POST.get('file2','')

        with open(file1, 'r') as t1, open(file2, 'r') as t2:
            fileone = t1.readlines()
            filetwo = t2.readlines()

        with open('update.csv', 'w') as outFile:
            for line in filetwo:
                if line not in fileone:
                    outFile.write(line)

        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="update.csv"'

        return response

    return render(request,'compare.html')
```

compare.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Comparision{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
                <h1 class="mb-3 display-4 text-light">Comparision</h1>
                <input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" class="form-control mt-3" required autofocus>
                <input type="file" id="file2" name="file2" class="form-control mt-3" required autofocus>
                <button class="mt-3 col-md-3 btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block" type="submit">Compare</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are uploading files through form, then add [**`enctype="multipart/form-data"`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads) in the html form tag:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}  # rest of the form
```

Then, you need to read the file from `request.FILES`, like this:

```
file1  = request.FILES['file1'].read().decode("utf-8")
file2  = request.FILES['file2'].read().decode("utf-8")
```

Now, you can read the files like this:

```
lines = file1.split("\n")   
for line in lines:                      
    fields = line.split(",")
```

Finally, when outputting the csv, You can use [**`django's example`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/outputting-csv/#using-the-python-csv-library) for outputting csv. Like this:

```
import csv
from django.http import HttpResponse

def comp(request):
    # rest of the code
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    updated_csv_list = []
    for line in file1:
       updated_csv_list.append(line.split(','))

    for line in file2:
        llist = line.split(',')
        if llist not in updated_csv_list:
             updated_csv_list.append(llist)

    for line in updated_csv_list:
        writer.writerow(line)

    return response
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now " 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'FILE' "

Comment: opps. my bad. it should be request.FILES

Comment: after correcting FILES, there comes another error " a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' ". Now, please tell me what is this?

Comment: Yes, that works. But why the update.csv is empty? there is only " in the file

Comment: not sure, can you try to debug if its properly populating `updated_csv_list`? Also, if the size of csv is big, then you can checkout this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files